# How do we change Field Names in our existing Users table in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-migrations

I am trying to Edit Users Table in Django. I am using Users Table to login or register a users. I have to add a new field name Role in that Table but i can't find any option to edit that existing table in admin section.

i just try to field some files to field out where the code of that existing Table is but did't get it.
is there any way to Edit the Table or I have to Create a New Table and have to create a new method of registration.
i am not expert so it's hard to me understand things.[image: Django Existing Users Table]

[image: The 'Role' field i want to add with other fields like username or email]

Comment: See https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: i think django not provide us directly this feature, but you can use same Form functions by creating new form and also use the same table and that's help you to same builtin function of django for using the Django Form.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, the Django admin interface **it's just for performing CRUD operations over already existing models**, you are not able to change in any way the database tables (at lest not using the "out of the box features") using the admin interface.

Said that in order to do what you want to do, with any model (not just User), you should:

1. Add the field to the model.
2. Instruct the admin interface to list this fields along the others.

Now the user model is kind of a special model here so I'll recommend a couple of readings you should complete before go forward with the model User customization.

References (User customization): [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model),  [Extending the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

And for the admin interface ...

Reference (admin interface): [ModelAdmin options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options), special  attention here to `list_display`

Comment: thanks for the reading links i will contact you after reading these links.